# How to set style as important from within GWT code?

Tags: gwt, coding-style

I've the following style that I need to set at run-time from within GWT code:

`margin: 0 0 0 -6px !important;`

I've tried the following which didn't work:

```
Style style = htmlProductSearch.getElement().getStyle();
style.setProperty("margin", "0 0 0 -6px !important");
```

However, when I removed the `!important` from the string, it works.. but I urgently need to make this style important.

Also I've used the setters methods `setMarginxxxx` but didn't work too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

htmlProductSearch.getElement().setAttribute("style","margin : 0 0 0 -6px !important");
Hope this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but you can use the `addStyleName` to add a css style.

In this css style you can use the `!important`.

This will work I think

Answer (score 1):

With elemental2 you can use

```
style.setProperty(propertyName, value, "important");
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all I must prevent you from using the `!important` clause, since it defeats the same concept of cascading.

But if you don't have other choice, you can make it work removing the shorthand sytle. This should work for you:

```
margin-left: -6px !important;
```